# React: Keep getting error: `Unterminated string constant` when trying to pass a string as a prop

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting the error `Unterminated string constant` pointing to my Foo string .  I tried passing the string a few different ways.  The first way, I was trying to directly pass the string as the prop but this latest way, I made a variable with the string value and passed it that way however, they all result in the same error.

```
render: function() {

    let foo = "Here is My Header";

    return (
                <div>
                     <ChildComponent 
                        header = {foo}
                     />
                </div>
             )
```

Comment: Please add the full code

Comment: Add all relevant code, and specify what line exactly the error is occurring. Can't see any issue with the snippet you've got.